# Applying an Excel formula to each group of a column which is specified by other column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two columns of data in Excel. Each rows of first column is like 1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,... As you can see, the same consecutive values are used in order to indicate that the valus on the other column belong to the same group (Number of repetition of each number is not the same but most of the time it is between 30 to 40 and the numbers go till 250). Now I want to apply a function to each group of column 2 (not entire the column). To be specific I want to subtract each value on the second column from maximum of the numbers of each group and display the result in another column. I know that I can do nested IFs formula but it is time consuming. I'm wondering if it is possible to do this task more efficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if I understood you correctly and if you have MAXIFS function in your Excel. If both are true you can use formulas like in the following screenshot.
[image: MAXIFS]
Formula in `C1` is for 1 cell only and you can copy it as required.
Formula in `D1` is a dynamic formula you can use in new Excel (2021, 365). It fills the entire column at once.